# Producing subgraph when querying through the neo4j web interface

Tags: neo4j

I am a newbie to `neo4j`, and basically I am trying to produce a subgraph from the whole graph according to certain rules. However, my current output does not meet what I want.

Suppose I have four nodes on the graph, which are `A, B, C, D`, and they are connected as:

```
A -- B
B -- C
C -- D
```

Basically I want to acquire a subgraph (or I would say it is **two traces**), consisting 4 nodes, and **two** edges:

```
A -- B
C -- D
```

However, when I use a `Cypher` code to query through the neo4j web interface, I always got the whole graph.. That means, I always get a graph with 4 nodes and **three** edges.

The `Cypher` query is something like below:

```
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n.id = "ID_A" and m.id = "ID_B" 
UNION
MATCH (n)-[r]-(m) where n.id = "ID_C" and m.id = "ID_D"
```

To be more specific, for the above query, I wish I can a subgraph with two traces, however, all three edges are shown in the output, connecting these four nodes.

Am I clear? Could anyone give me some help on how to produce the subgraph? Thank you!

Comment: Try to disable `auto-complete`: http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/

Comment: @stdob--  Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the auto-completion option works. Disable it in the browser interface.

[ http://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/ ]